# RMySQL: internal error in RS_DBI_getConnection: corrupt connection handle

Tags: r, shiny, rmysql

So I connected to my database just fine in the beginning:

```
con <- dbConnect(
MySQL(),
user = "username", password = "password",
host = "<my amazon web service database server>",
port = 3306
)
```

So everything was working but after a couple runs/refreshes on my Shiny app, it says I have 16 connections open and I can no longer open any connections.

So, I tried running:

```
dbDisconnect(dbListConnections(MySQL()))
```

Then I got this:

```
dbListConnections(MySQL())
[[1]]TRUE
```

Then I got this error:

```
Error in .local(dbObj, ...) : 
internal error in RS_DBI_getConnection: corrupt connection handle
```

Now, whenever I try to open my Shiny app, I get the error on the datatableoutput

```
(I query the database to generate this output):
internal error in RS_DBI_getConnection: corrupt connection handle
```

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same issue. This is how I solved it:

I was creating a connection and then some functions where using that connection. The thing is, the connection was in the outer scope:

```
con <- dbConnect(
  MySQL(),
  ...
)

MyFunction <- function(){
  myQuery <- paste("SELECT * FROM ...")
  df <- dbGetQuery(con, myQuery)
  df
}
```

For me too this worked fine, but stopped working after the "16" connections limit as in your case (same corrupt connection handle error).

**Workaround**

Create the connection inside of the function and disconnect at the end of the function:

```
MyFunction <- function(){

  con <- dbConnect(
    MySQL(),
    ...
  )

  myQuery <- paste("SELECT * FROM ...")
  df <- dbGetQuery(con, myQuery)

  dbDisconnect(con)
  df
}
```

Everything seems to be working now.